# phpmailer email sometimes not sent and sometimes taking too much time to send

Tags: php, phpmailer

i'm using godaddy hosting and porkbun domain and cloudflare dns, i'm using phpmailer for sending emails but it sometimes send mail too late or sometimes it even don't send the mail.

my codes are following, please suggest me some feedback so that i could fix it

```
try{
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
        $mail->Username = 'info@collegemitra.net.in';
        $mail->Password = '#';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
            // $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('info@collegemitra.net.in', 'CollegeMitra.net.in');
        $mail->addAddress($email);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'College List Based On Your Percentile';
        $mail->Body = '<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 {
        color: #00b0ff;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 40px 0;
      }
      p {
        color: #130f40;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin: 30px 0;
      }
      ul {
        color: #130f40;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin: 30px 0;
      }
      .link {
        color: #00b0ff;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #00b0ff;
      }
      span{
        color: #ff7800;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Hii <span>'.$name.'</span></h1>
      <p style="font-size: 130%;">Thank you for using our service! If you feel any kind of difficulty in the counselling process, <a href="https://collegemitra.net.in" class="link">collegemitra</a> is always there to help with our tremendous and affordable premium service.</p>
      <br>
      <p style="color: rgb(102, 98, 98);" class="regards">Regards Collegemitra</p>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
';
        // $mail->Body = 'Hii';
        $mail->addAttachment($newPDF);
        $mail->send();

        echo 'Mail Has been sent!';
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'danger, Something went wrong, Please try again later!';
    }
```

i expect that my phpmail will send email faster

Comment: The time for code execution is taking long, or the time between code execution completion and email delivery? How large is `$newPDF` and does its content vary or always the same?

Comment: the time between completion and delivery is long and $newPDF is almost same for every email

Comment: Copy message headers on an email delivered and run them in https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/analyzeheader. See if there's a delay in network somewhere

Comment: Godaddy’s email is terrible; how long it takes is not within PHPMailer’s control.

Comment: that's why i'm now in very big trouble, can't you tell me any way to get out of it